# Web API parameter binding failing odding on [Required] attribute

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, json.net

I have a web api with a controller method as such:

```
[Route("{player}/title(gameA)/appearance")]
public async Task<string> PutAppearance([ModelBinder]Player player, [FromBody] PlayerAppearance appearance){ //...stuff}
```

Player appearance looks like this:

```
 public class PlayerAppearance : PlayerAppearanceBase {///stuff}
```

and PlayerBase

```
    public abstract class PlayerAppearanceBase : IPlayerAppearance
{
    [Required]
    public string PlayerId { get; set; }

    public string TitleId{ get; set; }
```

When I send it a request with an appropriate request like such:

```
{"PlayerId":"123456","LastModified":"0001-01-01T00:00:00","TitleId":"gameA"}
```

I get the following error:

```
"ModelState":{"appearance.PlayerId":["The PlayerId field is required."]}
```

Now when I change my controller to look like this:

```
public async Task<string> PutAppearance([ModelBinder]Player player)
    {
        var appearance =
            JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<PlayerAppearance>(Request.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result); 
///...}
```

Everything works. Why does it freak out when it comes to simple parameter binding but it works fine when deserialized directly. What's going on behind the scenes that I'm missing?

*Note, I've clipped extraneous values out of my PlayerAppearance class

Comment: Your `PlayerAppearance` has a required `PlayerId` member so that's why you're getting the error when that parameter is included in the signature. Obviously if you take it out, it no longer would be required. I'm not sure what you're asking. Is 'PlayerAppearanceBase` a base class for `Player` as well?

Comment: Sorry, I've updated my question with the request payload being sent. The json submitted definitely has the PlayerId in there. What I did in the last code block is take it out of the controller function parameter (so Web API no longer tries to automagically bind it from the request body to the input param) and simply extract it directly from the request body and deserialize it myself (using the JsonConvert method). What I don't understand is why that works but the binding via the [frombody] parameter binding doesn't.

Comment: And yes, PlayerAppearanceBase is an abstract class with basic fields. I then have various implementations for different titles (e.g. "Game A", "Game B", "Game A: The Sequel"). The base class is the one with the required field.

Comment: You can only use a single `[FromBody]` attribute in the signature. What does the `Player` class look like? Also what attributes does your `controller` have?

Comment: Ah good point. Sorry, I clipped some information for simplicity sake but it is key. I'm using attribute based routing so the controller methods define the route in them (I've added it above). Player comes from the URL and the model binder does a lookup to another service to set the player object.